# GROUP BY problem on WHEN in CASE statement

Tags: sql, group-by, count, pivot

I'm trying to have the indirect and direct hours all show on one row and I know multiple rows are showing up because of the group by statement.  However, I've tried removing the grouping and get an error that the l.CHG_TYPE is not included in an aggregate when removed.

```html
<html><table><body><tr><th>ID</th><th>Billing Period</th><th>Shop</th><th>Shift Code</th><th>Employee #</th><th>Indirect Hours</th><th>Direct Hours</th></tr><tr class="odd"><td>202001404223396</td><td>202001</td><td>Sanitation</td><td>1st</td><td>23396</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>12.73</td></tr>
<tr><td>202001404223396</td><td>202001</td><td>Sanitation</td><td>1st</td><td>23396</td><td>6.41</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td>202001205225499</td><td>202001</td><td>Car Shop</td><td>1st</td><td>25499</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>12.4</td></tr>
<tr><td>202001205225499</td><td>202001</td><td>Car Shop</td><td>1st</td><td>25499</td><td>6.82</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(l.FISC_PD, l.LOCATION, l.SHIFT_CODE, e.EmpNo) 'ID',
    l.FISC_PD 'Billing Period', 
    CASE
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '202' THEN 'Specialty Equipment' 
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '205' THEN 'Car Shop'
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '206' THEN 'Truck Shop'
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '404' THEN 'Sanitation'
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '212' THEN 'Tire Shop'
        ELSE l.LOCATION
    END as 'Shop',
    CASE
        WHEN l.SHIFT_CODE in ('2','6') THEN '1st'
        WHEN l.SHIFT_CODE in ('3','4','5') THEN '2nd'
        ELSE NULL
    END as 'Shift Code',
    e.EmpNo 'Employee #',
    CASE
        WHEN l.CHG_TYPE = 'I' THEN ROUND((SUM(l.DURATION)/36000000),2)
        ELSE NULL
    END as 'Indirect Hours',
    CASE
        WHEN l.CHG_TYPE = 'D' THEN ROUND((SUM(l.DURATION)/36000000),2)
        ELSE NULL
    END as 'Direct Hours'
FROM m5prod.mfive.VIEW_EMP_LABOR_JNL l
LEFT JOIN m5prod.mfive.VIEW_ALL_EMPLOYEES e on e.EmpID = l.EMP_ID
WHERE 
    l.location not in ('218', '201')
    and l.FISC_PD in ('202001', '202002', '202003')
GROUP BY
    l.FISC_PD,  
    e.EmpNo,
    l.LOCATION,
    l.SHIFT_CODE,
    l.CHG_TYPE
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: I don't see any columns like FISC_PD, CHG_TYPE in your example.  Is there some sort of mapping between your user friendly column names and the column names in your SQL code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

- remove `CHG_TYPE` from the `GROUP BY` clause
- move the `CASE` expression *within* the `SUM()`

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(l.FISC_PD, l.LOCATION, l.SHIFT_CODE, e.EmpNo) 'ID',
    l.FISC_PD 'Billing Period', 
    CASE
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '202' THEN 'Specialty Equipment' 
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '205' THEN 'Car Shop'
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '206' THEN 'Truck Shop'
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '404' THEN 'Sanitation'
        WHEN l.LOCATION = '212' THEN 'Tire Shop'
        ELSE l.LOCATION
    END as 'Shop',
    CASE
        WHEN l.SHIFT_CODE in ('2','6') THEN '1st'
        WHEN l.SHIFT_CODE in ('3','4','5') THEN '2nd'
        ELSE NULL
    END as 'Shift Code',
    e.EmpNo 'Employee #',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN l.CHG_TYPE = 'I' THEN l.DURATION END)/36000000),2) as 'Indirect Hours',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN l.CHG_TYPE = 'D' THEN l.DURATION END)/36000000),2) as 'Direct Hours'
FROM m5prod.mfive.VIEW_EMP_LABOR_JNL l
LEFT JOIN m5prod.mfive.VIEW_ALL_EMPLOYEES e on e.EmpID = l.EMP_ID
WHERE 
    l.location not in ('218', '201')
    and l.FISC_PD in ('202001', '202002', '202003')
GROUP BY
    l.FISC_PD,  
    e.EmpNo,
    l.LOCATION,
    l.SHIFT_CODE
```

Side note: it is not a good practice to use single quotes for column aliases. In standard SQL, single quotes are reserved for string litterals. I would suggest using the relevant quote character for your database (MySQL: backticks - SQL Server: square brackets - Postgres and Oracle: double quotes). Better yet, you can use column aliases that do not contain special characters, so they don't need to be quoted.

Comment: We had the same idea. You got my upvote, and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @GMB thanks for the advice!  I'm fairly new to SQL and have been self-teaching myself.  From what you've said it's better for column aliases to not contain special characters at all.  Is there a best practice on syntax? Camel case?

Comment: @TrevorCorso: they contain spaces. You can use camel case, or better yet replaces spaces with an underscore (since lots of database engines by default capitalize the identifiers anyway, camel case is not necessarily a good thing).

Comment: @GMB thanks I'll start using underscores in my future statements.  You've been very helpful!